# Removing top and right axis in tikzpicture

Tags: pgfplots

Is it possible to remove the canvas borders when using the {axis} inside tikzpicture. The end goal is to remove the right and top border.

```
\begin{axis}[
   height=\figH,
   tick align=outside,
   tick pos=left,
   width=\figW,
   x grid style={darkgray176},
   xlabel={time},
   xmajorgrids,
   xmin=0, xmax=1000,
   xminorgrids,
   xtick style={color=black},
   y grid style={darkgray176},
   ylabel={signal},
   ymajorgrids,
   ymin=-5, ymax=5,
   yminorgrids,
   ytick style={color=black}
]
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please extend your code to a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: See section 4.9.9 (Axis Lines) in `pgfplots` documentation (Revision 1.18.1).